# Unable to copy file form one drive to another using PHP in windows

Tags: php, windows, copy

I was trying to create a file using PHP and trying to copy the created file to another drive using the following code

```
<?php
$file = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\testfile.txt';
$myfile = fopen( $file, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "This is a test";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
copy($file,'Y:\test.txt');
```

It is not working, It shows a warning and not copying the created file to the destination.

> Warning: copy(Y:\test.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\createfile.php on line 7

Is it possible to fix this issue?

Comment: Does the PHP user have permissions to copy to that folder on that drive?

Comment: @JayBlanchard It is a network mapped drive

Comment: Just because it is mapped doesn't mean that the PHP script has permission to write to it. Mappings are not available to the IUSR account.

Comment: Do you know how to check it?

Comment: PHP runs under the IUSR account.

Comment: I created the service using httpd.exe -k install -n "apacheservice"